# Inserting default image if there is not enough images

Tags: php, image, default

I have an album page which shows 4 images. I want to show a default image if there are less images than 4. I mean if there are 2 images, I want to show default image for 2 times for styling concerns.

I can count images in database like this:

```
 <?php
 $q2=mysql_query("select * from images where i_id=$id");
 $count =  mysql_num_rows($q);
```

And I can find the result like this:

```
 $result= 4 - $count;
```

But I can't realize how to set up if clause. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if ($count < 4) { ... }`?

Comment: Yes, but if it's 3, it must insert 1 default image, if it's 2, it must insert 2 default images, and so on. I can't realize how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$to_display = 4;
$query = mysql_query("select * from images where i_id=$id");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

     echo '<img src="img from db">';
     $displayed_number++;

}

echo str_repeat('<img src="default image">', $to_display-$displayed_number);
```

Comment: This one works like a charm! Thank you Norton!

Comment: Dear Norton, how can I divide this code to 2 rows (2 cells in each) ?

Comment: after $displayed_number++; add if ($displayed_number==2) echo '<br />';

Answer (score 1):

Okay you want this:

```
$imagesToShow = 4;

for ($i = $count; $i < $imagesToShow; $i++) {
    // print your default image here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Colin, I'm trying it now

Comment: Dear Colin, this code works also but it shows 1 more default image, I mean if there are 2 images, it shows 3 defult images. Anyway Norton's answer works as I want. Thank you again.